# Strategies to reduce redundant data on join

Tags: sql, sql-server

My production query has 10 joins with a select which has large text columns.
The problem is that some searches returns more that 8mb of data.. 7mb from duplicate data because of join. something like the image above but much bigger.

[image]

My example of tables structure:

```
create table A (
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    Value varchar(100)
)

create table B(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    AId int,
    Value varchar(100)
)

create table C(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    BId int,
    Value varchar(100)
)
```

Inserts:

```
insert into A values ('value A1')
insert into A values ('value A2')
insert into A values ('value A3')

insert into B values(1, 'value B1')
insert into B values(1, 'value B2')
insert into B values(1, 'value B3')

insert into C values(1, 'value C1')
insert into C values(1, 'value C2')
insert into C values(1, 'value C3')
```

How can I return only necessary data in a smart way with the same performance of join or better?

Command used to execute the query was:

```
select * from A 
left join B on A.Id = B.AId
left join C on C.BId = B.Id
where A.Id = 1
```

Comment: You have to tell us what format you want the data to be in.  We can't really provide that information.

Comment: How are the tables related? Usually when I see duplicated records in a `join` it's because I've overlooked one or more fields that should be included in the `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just want to avoid data marked in red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to return only the first appearance of the values:

```
select A.Id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by a.id order by b.id, c.id) = 1
             then a.value
        end) as a_value,
       B.id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by a.id, b.id order by c.id) = 1
             then b.value
        end) as b_value,
       C.id,
       C.value
from A left join
     B
     on A.Id = B.AId left join
     C
     on C.BId = B.Id
where A.Id = 1
order by a.id, b.id, c.id;
```